# FacebookSDK - How to output results from a facebook call?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am using FacebookSDK (ASP.Net MVC Facebook Canvas Application) and I am just trying to output the video id from two videos I have uploaded to Facebook.  Using the SDK I have successfully retrieved the videos and it says it has the two videos however I am not sure how to write the code to grab and output the video ids themselves?

My *Action* looks like this:

```
    FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();

    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

    parameters.fields = "id,videos";

    dynamic result = app.Api("me", parameters);

    return View(result);
```

When I step through the code in ASP.Net and mouse over result after it has called app.API it says I have a Facebook.JsonObject with two items in it.  One is my facebook userid the other is another Facebook.JsonObject with the two videos inside it.  So my conclusion is that it is returning the user id and the videos associated to that user.  That makes sense, but what is the best approach in outputting these types of structures?

My *View* looks like this:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
```

`<% foreach (var video in Model) { %>
    <object width="352" height="221" >
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/<%: video.id %>" />
        <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/<%: video.id %>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="352" height="221"></embed>
    </object>
<% } %>`

The above *View* is not working with an error saying it cannot find video.id.  My guess is that I need to understand dynamic data types better and how the Facebook.JsonObject works.

Anybody that has experience using the FacebookSDK and can help me to extract the video id from my facebook videos I would be much appreciated.

Do I need to create a separate ViewModel Class specifically that has a user id and List type that holds the videos??

Cheers
Rob

Answer (score 0):

With this code it should work but you won't have your user id.

```
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();

dynamic result = app.Api("me/videos");

return View(result.data);
```

If you really want it you can still create a ViewModel object to store the user id and the videos.

```
public class VideosViewModel{

   public dynamic userId {get;set;}

   public dynamic videos {get;set;}

}
```

Code in your action:

```
FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();

var VideosViewModel vvm = new VideosViewModel();

dynamic result = app.Api("me/videos"); 

vvm.videos = result.data;

dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject(); 

parameters.fields = "id"; 

dynamic result = app.Api("me", parameters); 

vvm.userId = app.Api("me");

return View(vvm);
```

In your view use Model.videos

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>


<% foreach (var video in Model.videos) { %>
    <object width="352" height="221" >
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/<%: video.id %>" />
        <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/<%: video.id %>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="352" height="221"></embed>
    </object>
<% } %>
```

You can also find interresting example here:

http://www.facebook.com/notes/nathan-totten/dynamic-objects-and-the-facebook-c-sdk/158611014180033

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct way to do this after some research I did last night:

*Action* should look like this:

```
    FacebookApp app = new FacebookApp();

    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();

    parameters.fields = "id,name";

    dynamic result = app.Api("me/videos/uploaded", parameters);

    return View(result);
```

*View* should look like this:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>
```

`<% foreach (var video in Model.data) { %>
    <object width="352" height="221" >
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.facebook.com/v/<%: video.id %>" />
        <embed src="http://www.facebook.com/v/<%: video.id %>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="352" height="221"></embed>
    </object>
<% } %>`

The problem was two fold:

1) My URI path was incorrect, it should be:

dynamic result = app.Api("me/videos/uploaded", parameters);

2) When I said that I was getting the videos back in actual fact I was only getting back the user id and an empty data set for the videos.  So in reality it boiled down to the fact that my URI was incorrect.

3) When outputting the results I should have set the pointer to start at:

Model.data rather than Model itself.

@MrKow thanks for your feedback and help with this problem the link you provided is invaluable.  I've book marked it for future reference :-)

Cheers
Rob